# Converting mcrypt_encrypt to openssl_encrypt in PHP

Tags: php, encryption, openssl, mcrypt

As **mcrypt_encrypt** is removed from PHP 8, I need to convert the following code to using **openssl_encrypt**

```
function encryptValue($input,$sKey)
{   
    $key = hex2bin($sKey);
    
    $block = mcrypt_get_block_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
    $pad = $block - (strlen($input) % $block);
    $input .= str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad);
    
    $encrypted_text = bin2hex(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $input, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB));  

    return $encrypted_text;
}
```

I have it replaced by the following:

```
function encryptData($input, $sKey)
    {
        $key= hex2bin($sKey);

        $encrypted_text = bin2hex(openssl_encrypt($input, 'AES-256-ECB', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA));
        return $encrypted_text;
    }
```

As **openssl** does default padding, I did not pad the plaintext like in the original code. I believe the secret key is being converted to binary. If I leave out the key conversion from both code, then I get the same encrypted text. But if I use the key conversion, then the encrypted texts are different.

If I remove the below code from both, then both returns the same encrypted text.

```
$key= hex2bin($sKey);
```

But without this, it will not work with the external API.

Comment: Your code "$key .= chr(hexdec($sKey[$i].$sKey[$i+1]))" is a "hexstring to string" converter, e.g. the input "31323334353637386162636465666768" gets converted to "12345678abcdefgh". Now everything depends on the **key length** - when using my sample string you have a 16 characters/bytes long AES key that is good for **AES-128** and not **AES-256** as you used in your function. Using a doubled input key will need **AES-256** in your openssl-code. It could be helpful if you could give a sample key with resulting ciphertext if my answer didn't solve your problem.

Comment: `$inputVal` isn't defined in both snippets. This must be changed to `$input`. Probably a copy/paste issue. When this is fixed, both codes return the same ciphertext (as long as both codes use the key conversion consistently). Btw, the key conversion is functionally identical to `hex2bin()`.

Comment: @MichaelFehr example key: **2ca8a887d4cc71dd68785c2ebe11a6aa** This is a real key. This goes through the **hex2bin** function, and it returns some unicode characters. Then this is passed to the encryption function. Also, am using **AES-256-ECB** with openssl since that is the key size.

Comment: @user9014097 Edited the question. When not using the key conversion **hex2bin** both return the same ciphertext. But when both use the key conversion, the ciphertexts are different. Don't know what's happening. And it needs the key conversion since the receiving API probably uses that in decryption as well.

Comment: Also in the 1st snippet, change `$inputVal` to `$input`. Currently you do not use the padded plaintext.

Comment: @MichaelFehr finally found the answer after your help. That hex2bin converts my 256 bit key into a 128 bit key requiring me to use AES-128-ECB instead of AES-256-ECB. When not using hex2bin, it was giving the same ciphertext with AES-256 but not with AES-128. Anyway, don't know if you can turn your comment into an answer, if you can, I can mark it as the answer. Thanks.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem with the posted codes, both give the same result, s. online [here, change to v5.6.29](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9f85bb4f19b01290875d4db93b3d35051e70b896) and [here](https://paiza.io/projects/XthVyl49Sc2BHJcUp18bIA). Anyway, you seemed to have solved the problem with Michael Fehr's comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code `"$key .= chr(hexdec($sKey[$i].$sKey[$i+1]))"` is a "hexstring to string" converter, e.g. the input "31323334353637386162636465666768" gets converted to "12345678abcdefgh".

Now everything depends on the key length - when using my sample string you have a 16 characters/bytes long AES key that is good for **AES-128** and **not AES-256** as you used in your function.

Using a doubled input key will need **AES-256** in your openssl-code.

It could be helpful if you could give a sample key with resulting ciphertext if my answer didn't solve your problem.